# Java replace character with a string in a string

Tags: java, string, replace

Could you suggest where I am making mistake:

```
  public static char[] replaceSpaces(String string){
    int length = string.length();
    int spaceCount = 0;
    for(int i =0; i<=length-1;i++){if(string.charAt(i)==' '){spaceCount++;}}

    int index = length + spaceCount*2;
    char[] charString = new char[index];
    int k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<index-1;i++){

        if(string.charAt(k) == ' '){
            charString[i] = '%';
            charString[i+1] = '2';
            charString[i+2] = '0';
            i = i +2;
            k=k+1;}
        else
            charString[i] = string.charAt(k);
            k++;
    }
    return charString;}

}
```

It outputs **wa%20cf** whereas I I want "wa%20dcf" as oputput. Basically I am replacing every space with "%20". Also this code doesn't work for two or more spaces.

Comment: Why aren't you just using `String.replace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use `String.replace()`

Simple mistake, you forgot braces for your else statement so either do this

```
else
{
    charString[i] = string.charAt(k);
    k++;
}
```

or since `k= k+1` is equivalent to `k++` change your for to this

```
for(int i = 0; i < index; i++) // also change your index 
{
    if(string.charAt(k) == ' ')
    {
        charString[i] = '%';
        charString[i+1] = '2';
        charString[i+2] = '0';
        i = i +2;
    }
    else
    { // these braces are not needed now but inculde them to make my 
      // point above valid
        charString[i] = string.charAt(k);
    }
    //increment every time
    k++;
}
```

This will fix both issues you are having

Answer (score 5):

Why do you want to write your own method?

```
String yourString = "my test string".replace(" ", "%20");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a replaceAll() method you can use:

```
         String newString = string.replaceAll(" ","%20");
```

Comment: Why use `replaceAll` over `replace` here?

Comment: For his purposes they both work the same, but replaceAll adds the ability to use regular expressions as well.

Comment: I can't use the repalceAll or replace methods as part of the assignment.